# labeling data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe. I want to classify my data like this:

```
if element > threshold:
    element = 1
elif element < -threshold:
    element = -1
else:
    element = 0
```

Trying to do it like this in pandas, but it obviously leaves out the range [-threshold,threshold].  Is there a way to use "else" on an entire column?

```
for col in data:
    data[col][data[col] > threshold] = 1
    data[col][data[col] < -threshold] = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.sign`

```
np.sign(data - threshold)
```